# How to whitelist domain in Unbound

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

I know that sometimes false positive can happen when using public blocklists, that way I want to import/create whitelist to make sure not to block them.

I've already checked manual from Unbound and searched but unfortunately didn't found the right answer. I'm searching etheir to make through conf file whitelist or RPZ zone, anything will work for me.

Comment: would you please explain more about public blocklits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution which I will post here if anyone else will need a help for this situation.

If you use RPZ zone then it should be used: `CNAME rpz-passthru.`.

If you use local-zone blocklist then it should be used:

```
local-zone: "example.com" always_transparent
```

Always_transparent makes queries to resolve normally.